# Automatically localize all numbers on a web page

Tags: html, web, localization, internationalization, translation

I'm wondering if there is a programmatic way of detecting all instances of numbers on a web page (e.g. 1, 34, 558, 6, etc.) and convert them to equivalents in other languages of the site.

For example, if I have a bilingual site that has English and Arabic. On the English page there is a number "12345". It's coming from the database, so the numbers are stored as 12345 etc. in the database. Now, on the Arabic version of the site, I can translate all words etc. but numbers still show as 12345. I want to display Arabic numbers instead. It's impossible to translate the numbers because they are generated dynamically and keep changing.

I guess some sort of "on-the-fly" solution is what I'm looking for?

Comment: It's certainly possible. There's not really a particularly smart way to do it, just replace the numbers when they are being added to the page content if you are serving the arabic version of the page

Comment: If you could elaborate more with an example/code etc. it would be helpful, because this is still vague to me :)

Comment: are Arabic numbers different from English? clearly there is some difference, but I can't figure it out. quick google, this Arabic font has English looking numbers. http://www.dafont.com/alhambra.font  but I'm not so sure that's a font for Arab language, in context of your question, makes me think its just styled to look like Arabic. I think I have a solution for you, without programming anything, but I need an Arabic font for the demo.

Comment: @albert Arabic numbers are definitely different from English. There is a bit of confusion regarding the naming of the two since the current English numbers [are originally Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). [These](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) are the current Arabic numbers.

Comment: @Hassan i was pretty sure about that, thanks for clarification. know where i can get an open source font with those numbers?

Comment: @albert, no particular font is in my mind now, but i've found a couple on cooltext.com including [this one](http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-B+Jadid)

Comment: @hassan i can't see characters on my box. probably bc its westernized? i'll look for a solution. essentially you want to create two <code>font-family</code> declarations, english and arabic, and use ltr or rtl attribute on html element to swap out fonts for reach. or that is what i am thinking. can't test without proper materials. pretty sure it'll work though.

Comment: It would be best to do the formatting when you "assemble" the pieces together (the web page template + the data from the database). Global tinkering with the final page is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there will be a way in HTML on the fly, you're going to need a language with a bit more umph, Javascript or PHP for example. Someone else will have to show you a JS example, but for PHP, you can do:

```
function eng_to_arabic($strTextToChange)
  {
    $strArabicNumbs = array('٩','٨','٧','٦','٥','٤','٣','٢','١','٠');
    $strEnglishNumbs = range(0, 9);

    return str_replace($strArabicNumbs, $strEnglishNumbs, $strTextToChange);
  }
```

Then you can call the function with

```
echo eng_to_arabic($strSomeNumber);
```